# SSH change default terminal to other program on host

Tags: ssh

So, I'm creating a system, using `openssh`, and I would like to have clients connected to host switch to different program than shell automatically.

ie. let's say that I have a program `myapp`, that uses text interface. I want to configure the `openssh`, so when a client connects, they are welcomed with `myapp` automatically, and they don't use the shell at all.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found the answer - what I wanted to do, was to change the users' default shell.

You can do it, for example, when creating users, by:

```
useradd --shell= *path to myapp* user
```

Or using:

```
chsh -s *path to myapp* user
```